# Decorator pattern - am i doing it wrong?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I'm creating a Java based game. My game has objects of several different types: "player", "enemy" (with several different sub types), "scene objects". All those classes extend one abstract class that's common for all other "actor" objects and thus has considerable number of abstract and protected methods.

Now, i want to add a shadow for some objects in the game. In theory, that sounds like a perfect job for a decorator pattern right? The problem is that i don't know if i'm doing something wrong because applying a shadow decorator would require me to implement all those abstract methods from my "root" class. That's not so easy because my root class is rather complex (there's physics involved, key-press listeners etc). Also, the way "player" behaves is not so similar to the way "scene object" behaves. I can't just implement "shadow" in a top class because sometimes i want a certain "actor" on the scene to lose it's shadow dynamically.

That's why i have few doubts:

1) should i even consider implementing decorator in situations like this?

2) if yes, how to painlessly implement a decorator that decorates complex base abstract classes?

Comment: I'd advise you to think about your design. "Complex base abstract class" sounds already like a codesmell :-), refactor it into a simple base abstract class. I wouldn't use decorator here: "game object HAS a shadow" (composition). Nothing wrong with making `IEffect` proerty on your class, and letting instances of something to be injected if neeed, for example, instance of `ShadowEffect` class.

Comment: Ah! Seems like a good idea! So, you're telling me to implement "IEffect" which will drop shadow (defined by "ShadowEffect") in case "ShadowEffect" object has been passed, right?

Comment: great, can you just post the answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Why do you think decorator is the pattern for you? Decorator allows you to "augment" an existing method in your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to think about your design. "Complex base abstract class" sounds already like a codesmell :-), refactor it into a simple base abstract class. I wouldn't use decorator here: "game object HAS a shadow" (composition).

Nothing wrong with making **IEffect** property on your class, and letting instances of something to be injected if needed, for example, instance of ShadowEffect class.

```
public IEffect {}
public DropShadowEffect : IEffect{}

public IGameObject{
   IEffect Effect;
}

public MyGameObject : IGameObject
{
   public IEffect Effect;

   public MyGameObject(IEffect effect){
     Effect = effect;
   }
}

public MySceneRenderer : IGameSceneRenderer {
   public List<IGameObject> _objects;

   public void Render(){
     foreach(var obj in _objects){
        var effect = obj.Effect;
        // blit the obj into a screen,
        // and apply the effect.
     }
   }
}
```

(Just noticed this is JAva, not C#, but this is essentially design question anyways).